# Why does UITabBarController sometimes call ViewDidLoad during its construction?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm working with a class derived from UITabBarController at present.

When I load the tab bar as the topmost view during AppDelegate setup then the constructor is called first, and then, after construction is complete, ViewDidLoad is invoked.

However, if I create the tab view controller later in my app (e.g. as a second or third "page"), then the virtual ViewDidLoad call is made during the construction of the UITabBarController. This isn't causing any virtual function table problems (the child class is being invoked) but it is causing particular problems for me because I can't access any construction parameters in ViewDidLoad.

As a workaround, I'm simply detecting the early firing of the ViewDidLoad() and adding a later call during my own constructor. But I'd quite like to understand what is going on: why does UITabBarController sometimes call ViewDidLoad during its construction?

Comment: Are directly accessing the controller's view? Apple's documentation states that you "should never do that". If you make your controller the root controller, you should use window.RootController = yourController. What do you mean by "2nd or 3rd page"? Are you adding the controller's view as a subview to some other view? That's probably not a good idea. To give you more help, some example code would help a lot.

Comment: The ViewController I'm currently looking at is: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/master/Sample%20-%20Tutorial/Tutorial/Tutorial.UI.Touch/Views/Lessons/CompositeView.cs. The way it's loaded is complicated to explain... however the actual construction is simple - it's during the new call (during the UITabBarController constructor) that the virtual ViewDidLoad call is occurring.

Comment: There is a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2700) that relates to this. I ended up working around it by using the stock UITabBarController and making sure any heavy lifting that would have been done with those parameters is now done before I create it. If this needs to be encapsulated further, I will put it in a static factory method that can consume what were my intended constructor parameters.